# Logistic regression on pooled data on several years

Tags: r, time-series, logistic-regression

I have a database with N firms, and observations for several variables (both numeric and binary) for each firm per year.

As an example:

```
df <- data.frame(
"Year" = c (2010,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012)
"Firm" = c ("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C")
"Holding" = c (TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)
"Male CEO" = c (TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE))
```

I would like to check for an association between explanatory variables in time T (e.g. Revenue 2010, Holding 2010) and a dependent variable in T+1 (e.g. Male CEO 2011), of course not only on two years but for all the years on my sample. I am going to do it with a logistic regression.

My problem is not which model to use, but how to tell my model to take the dependent variable the year after the one of dependent variables, one year at a time. The way I modeled it right now it takes all the observations, no matter the year.

Do you have any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

### Thanks

EDIT:

for clarity, directly copying from my R file, this is how I set the model now.

```
CSR_Contracting <- lag(df$Policy_Executive_Compensation_ESG_Performance)

mod1 <- glm(df$CSR_Contracting ~
        + df$ESG_Score
        + df$Environmental_Pillar_Score
        + df$Social_Pillar_Score
        + df$Board_Cultural_Diversity_Percent_Score
        + df$Board_Gender_Diversity_Percent_Score
        + df$Policy_Board_Diversity
        + df$CSR_Sustainability_External_Audit
        + df$ROA
        + df$Size
        + df$PTB_Ratio
        + df$Leverage
        + df$CSR_Sustainability_Committee
        + df$Independent_Board_Members
        + df$CEO_Chairman_Separation
        + df$Chairman_is_ex_CEO
        + df$Policy_Equal_Voting_Right
        + df$Shareholders_Approval_Stock_Comp_Plan
        + df$Policy_Executive_Retention
        + df$Compensation_Improvement_Tools
        + df$Executive_Compensation_Policy
        + df$CEO_Compensation_Link_to_TSR
        + df$Executive_Compensation_LT_Objectives
        + df$Shareholders_Vote_on_Executive_Pay
        + df$Veto_Power_or_Golden_share
        + df$SOE,
         family = binomial, maxit=100)
```

Comment: How is your model looking like at this stage?

Comment: It sounds like you want to `lead()` or `lag()` one of your values but I'm not exactly clear. Specifically check out the `?dplyr::lead` help page.

Comment: @TarJae, @ MrFlick, I just edited the question to include the current model I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you mean, but on your data sample it can be done as follows.

```
library(tidyverse)
df = tibble(
  Year = c (2010,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012),
  Firm = c ("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"),
  Holding = c (TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),
  Male.CEO = c (TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)) %>% 
  mutate(Male.CEO.1 = lead(Male.CEO,3)) %>% 
  filter(Year != 2012)

df
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
# Year Firm  Holding Male.CEO Male.CEO.1
# <dbl> <chr> <lgl>   <lgl>    <lgl>     
# 1  2010 A     TRUE    TRUE     TRUE      
# 2  2010 B     FALSE   TRUE     FALSE     
# 3  2010 C     FALSE   TRUE     TRUE      
# 4  2011 A     FALSE   TRUE     TRUE      
# 5  2011 B     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE     
# 6  2011 C     FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  

glm(Male.CEO.1~Firm+ Holding, data=df)
# 
# Call:  glm(formula = Male.CEO.1 ~ Firm + Holding, data = df)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)        FirmB        FirmC  HoldingTRUE  
# 1.000e+00   -1.000e+00   -5.000e-01    1.249e-16  
# 
# Degrees of Freedom: 5 Total (i.e. Null);  2 Residual
# Null Deviance:        1.5 
# Residual Deviance: 0.5    AIC: 12.12
```

Note that to get `Male.CEO.1` at the time T+1 I used `lead (Male.CEO, 3)`. This, however, will only have a senst if there are exactly the same number of observations each year (in this example 3).